# Why are my room resources rejecting my invitations?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am writing a calendar interfacing app in python, with Google Apps.

I can add room resources to an event by adding them as one of the participants of the event.  This works, in practice, but it becomes hard to test, because after a certain number of event creations and cancels, the room starts declining my invitations, even when it has no other events during the specified time period.

It *seems* to be some sort of spam feature, it only happens when I test creating the event and then cancelling it several times in a row.

My calendar sharing settings are set to "Share All Information".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your calendar sharing is set to **Share All Information**, the event will still be declined if room resources has other settings. Suggested resolution is to ask the administrator to change the sharing options for the resource to **See all event details** or to give you specific permission to book the resource.

You may check [Why do resources reject my invitations?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1084813?hl=en) for more information.